# Zend MVC - design - onClick, load new view ? A view inside a view?

Tags: php, zend-framework, view

I have a page and, that page will fade out to display a new content (from another view).

In general terms, what should we have into consideration here?

Where should I dig in to make this possible?

Should I call a view inside another view, by using some sort of ajax?

```
class EquipasController extends OccControllerAction{

public function init(){

if ($this->getRequest()->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
 $this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('blank');
 //$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
 $logger = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('Log');
 $logger->debug('AJAX Call');
}

}


public function listaAction()
{
    echo ("I'm HERE??");
   $dados = array('dados1', 'dados2', 'dados3');
}

}


<h1>Tests...</h1>

<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array("controller"=>"equipas","action"=>"lista"), null, true); ?>" class="ajaxloader">Mostra Lista Sff</a>
<div id="testresults">
    <h1>Esta é uma coisa que aparece sempre.</h1>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $('.ajaxloader').click(function(event) {
            var target = $(this).attr('href');
            window.location.hash = target;
            $.ajax({
                  url: target,
                  success: function(data) {
                    $('#testresults').html(data);
                  }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I first load the page, all ok.
When I click the link, I actually get an ajax call (because I notice no refresh).
When it displays it displays the all page again.

It doesn't display the echo that i've put on listaAction ! :-(

**UPDATE:**

When I see my link URL on the browser I see:
http://mypage.org/equipas/registo#/equipas/lista

By on the anchor I have:
http://mypage.org/equipas/lista

Could the issue be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this exact thing before.  Here's a stripped down version of what I do.

1. Have a 'blank' layout.  This excludes any global header/content/css.
2. Have a 'smart' controller `init()` or plugin that will toggle between your default and blank layout if the request is ajax. Here's my (stripped) controller code:

   class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action
   {

   ```
   public function init()
   {
       /* Initialize action controller here */
       if ($this->getRequest()->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
           $this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('blank');
           $logger = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('Log');
           $logger->debug('AJAX Call');
       }
   }


   public function indexAction()
   {
       // render the default page
   }


   public function speedAction()
   {
       // Do stuff render something
   }


   public function somethingelseAction()
   {
       // do something else render something.
   }
   ```

   }
3. Have your initial view render with a target div, as well as some links that you want to go into that target.  Here's my index.phtml:

   ```
   <h1>Tests...</h1>
           <a class="ajaxloader"
               href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=> 'test', 'action' => 'speed'), null, true);?>">Speed</a>
           <a class="ajaxloader"
               href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=> 'test', 'action' => 'somethingelse'), null, true);?>">Something Else</a>
           <div id="testresults">
           <h1>Default stuff to show.</h1>
           </div>
   ```
4. Setup some jQuery code (however you like) to attach to these 'ajaxloader' links and target your results to the 'testresults' div.  Here's some basic JS:

   ```
   $(function() {
   $('.ajaxloader').click(function(event) {
       var target = $(this).attr('href');
       window.location.hash = target;
       $('#testresults').fadeOut('slow', function() {
           // complete fadeout, load new content while it's hiding!
           $.ajax( {
               url : target,
               success : function(data) {
                   $('#testresults').html(data);
                   $('#testresults').fadeIn();
               }
           });
       });
       return false;
   })
   });
   ```

All links clicked on that have the class 'ajaxloader' will be loaded via ajax and put into the 'testresults' div.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a closer look into your code just provided. Actually I would like to preserve the header and footer that as have as layouts already. Could this change something about the init() function above? Yes, I'm fairly new on all this. :D

Comment: The originally loaded header/footer/layout will be preserved.  The only thing that gets replaced is the contents inside the 'testresults' div.

Comment: Thanks again. One last question. If I want to do a fadeout of the view that has the initial link to the ajax request, and a fade in or the other view that will be presented, where should I place them?

Comment: in the javascript `success:` function you can fade out the existing testresults div, replace the content while it's hidden and then fade it back in.  Exact jquery syntax isn't coming to be but it's something smart like `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` on the element :)

Comment: Thanks Darryl I really appreciate your help on elucidate me on all this. :) That blank page is a layout that will be rendered on a given view on a given action that I choose to show some information, right? On your example, what will be the view that you are loading on that testresults ? (I'm really sorry for all those questions, reply if you feel like of course). K. Regards

Comment: :( I'm getting ALL the layout rendering. Once I click the link. :(

Comment: That's why you need a 'blank' layout. So only the contents of your view gets returned.  My `layouts/scripts/blank.phtml` contains one line: `<?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>`

Comment: (I have added a blank.phtml as well, with nothing then a div inside), I also have tried with disable layout. I will update my post with this try.

Comment: When you click the link do you see a `#/equipas/lista` show up in the address bar?  That's the only real indicator that the ajax call is working.  Also, make sure there's content in your view for lista - `lista.phtml` file.

Comment: Yes. When I click the link I see #/equipas/lista on my address bar. I don't know what it is (?), but I have it once I click. I have no view called lista. I have no view associated with lista controller. So, should I have one on this case? I'm doing an echo on my controller, shouldn't that display something on the view port? I will add a lista.phtml view. And should my view load the blank layout?

Comment: Hmmm.... On the controller, should I pass some data to the view that has the <script> part ?

Comment: The `<script>` should only be in the original view (`index.phtml` in my example) as well as the link to all the actions.  The other actions that get executed when you click the links (`lista` in your case) should only render the contents that you want to display.

Comment: The <script> as well as the links are on my edfault defined view. In this case: Test.phtml (properly defined as defaul on Acl.php). I would love that they render only the contents that I want. But I just get the all page again. x.x

Comment: @Darryl - thanks a lot for your time. I cannot ask you more. I will rest my case. I'm really not getting this ajax call thing.. prrff.

Comment: I'm not really sure what else to try. All I can say is that the things I've explained above work. - http://playground.darrylclarke.com/test - I'm not sure what else I can do for you at this time.

Comment: About your demo. I'm not sure if I can do this, but here it's not the case that I click on something, and something else get's fade in and out, here, I click on something and the container of that something will ALSO fade out. About the rest... Worry not. I'm really grateful for your explanation and it will sure serve me as a base. But I'm clearly missing something. And that could be due to the fact that I'm on 6 hours non stop into this. I will review this tomorrow morning and see what I get. Thanks a lot, really. :)

Comment: Good luck!  ps. I updated the javascript snippit to show you how you can fade out, replace the content and fade back in.  It's up and working on my demo site.

Comment: Hmm... do you see your link "Speed"? On my case, the "Speed" link should fade out, when I click on it. That's what I was tried to describe earlier. Don't need to code, I'm just wondering if the process will be the same. It's good to see if I'm not getting into a dead end. :)

Comment: To fade the actual link that gets clicked, just `$(this).fadeOut();`

Comment: new day. I will give another shot. :)

Comment: The application is not understanding that lista is a new controller action. Should I say somewhere on the framework that lista is a new action ? I know this because, if I remove lista from the controller, I get the same result. So the application is ignoring lista.

Comment: to create a new action in a controller you need the function for the action (which you have) as well as a view for the action (in `views/scripts/equipas/` a file called `lista.phtml`

Comment: I have both. But, if I do: http://www.mysite.com/equipas/lista/ I get my homepage. :s I was expecting to see some echo that ive put on listaAction() method. Or something. So, and I believe that this IS the issue. Because, with ajax or not, I need to first, be able to display something if I do: http://www.mysite.com/equipas/lista/ right? COuld it be something related with some zf configuration somewhere?

Comment: Are you using layouts?  If you are does your layout have this line: `<?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>` somewhere in it?  This sounds a lot like your layout is being displayed but your custom content is not.

Comment: If I do: mysite.com/equipas/lista I see my homepage with the index view. So I see the layout and the corresponded view. (but the wrong one). I'm using layouts, but none of my layouts, header.php footer.php have $this->layout()->content in them.

Comment: "layouts" as far as zend framework is concerned is a single file and the fact that you've stated 'header.php' and 'footer.php' screams to me that you're not actually using "layouts" as zend framework normally does...  This could be the bigger issue.

Comment: Well... I have them on my default/layouts/ folder and they are like general pages that will cross all website pages. hmm... Why are you saying that this is not a proper way for using them? (I will go right now to Zend home page manual and read about layouts).

Comment: AhhhhAAAAHHHHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!!! I was not allowing my view to work because the Acl.php was not having the proper configuration. I had to add: $this->allow('guest', 'default_equipas','lista'); Now I will take your example again and see what I get...

Comment: @Darryl  - You absolutly rock! I've just change your init() to one line: if ($this->getRequest()->isXMLHttpRequest()) 
{
 $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout(); 
}

and, added the proper Acl rule. :) I'm now able to load the view. Thanks you and thank you and thank you again. :)))) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If your page causes a portion to *fade out* then you must use JavaScript (or CSS animation or IE's old, awful propriety, `meta` tags).

I would use JavaScript to fetch a view via AJAX, and load it into an element on your page.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. So. For example, jquery load method mixed with Zend render("someviehere") ? - Can you sketch a little example for me please? :D